# Dynamically pass xml to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a temp table that has 2 columns.

```
CREATE TABLE #ExecuteThese
    (
        StoredProcedure nvarchar(200),
        Parameter xml
    )
```

What I am trying to do is in a cursor execute all the stored procedures in this temp table and pass the xml parameter to it, while also catching the return value of the procedure.

Am I on the right track? `@parameters` and `@storedProc` are cursor variables

```
-- Capture the return level code
DECLARE @returnLevel int
exec sp_executesql @storedProc, N'@parameters xml', @parameters, N'@returnLevel int output', @returnLevel output
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop on the identity column and dynamically execute statements

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.XmlProc', N'P') IS NOT NULL DROP PROC dbo.XmlProc
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.XmlProc
@xmlParam xml,
@paramOUT int OUTPUT
AS
SELECT @paramOUT = @XmlParam.value('/param[1]', 'nvarchar(1)')
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.XmlProc2', N'P') IS NOT NULL DROP PROC dbo.XmlProc2
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.XmlProc2
@xmlParam xml,
@paramOUT int OUTPUT
AS
SELECT @paramOUT = @XmlParam.value('/param[1]', 'nvarchar(1)')
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.XmlProc3', N'P') IS NOT NULL DROP PROC dbo.XmlProc3
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.XmlProc3
@xmlParam xml,
@paramOUT int OUTPUT
AS
SELECT @paramOUT = @XmlParam.value('/param[1]', 'nvarchar(1)')
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#ExecuteThese') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#ExecuteThese
CREATE TABLE dbo.#ExecuteThese
 (
  Id int IDENTITY,  
  StoredProcedure nvarchar(100),
  Parameter xml
  )

INSERT dbo.#ExecuteThese
VALUES('dbo.XmlProc @param, @paramOUT OUTPUT', '<param>1</param>'),
      ('dbo.XmlProc2 @param, @paramOUT OUTPUT', '<param>2</param>'),
      ('dbo.XmlProc3 @param, @paramOUT OUTPUT', '<param>3</param>')

DECLARE @id int = 1,          
        @param xml,
        @parmRET int,
        @dml nvarchar(max)  
WHILE (@id IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN     
  SELECT @dml = StoredProcedure, @param = Parameter 
  FROM dbo.#ExecuteThese
  WHERE Id = @Id  

  EXEC sp_executesql @dml, N'@param xml, @paramOUT int OUTPUT', @param, @parmRET OUTPUT
  SELECT @parmRET AS parmRET

  SELECT @id = MIN(Id) FROM dbo.#ExecuteThese WHERE Id > @Id
END
```